# Add class to each item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need some help, I'm new at vue.js. I have the following

```
<ul>
  <li class="disable"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li> //Currently doing mouseover
  <li class="disable"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I do a `mouseover` in an item and add an "active" class, and add a "disable" class to the other items?

"Basically what I want is that when I mouseover any item, the "active" class has a more "disable" class and when doing mouseout, just delete the class "disable" but keep the class "active" "

Comment: Do you know how to attach event listeners with Vue, and how to handle elements classes?

Comment: Have you considered approaching this from CSS: i.e `:hover`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming initially one is acive.

Switching between `disable` and `active` class without using css`:hover`.

```
 setLiActive(event){
    event.target.classList.remove('disable');
    event.target.classList.add('active');
 },
 setLiDisable(event){
    event.target.classList.remove('active');
    event.target.classList.add('disable');
 }
```

Using `mouseover` (to add active class) and `mouseleave` (to add disable class)

```
<ul>
  <li class="disable" @mouseleave="setLiDisable($event)"  @mouseover="setLiActive($event)" ><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="disable" @mouseleave="setLiDisable($event)" @mouseover="setLiActive($event)"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li> 
  <li class="disable"  @mouseleave="setLiDisable($event)"  @mouseover="setLiActive($event)"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
function callMe() {
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
     isActive:true
    },
    created(){
     
    },
    methods: {
     setLiActive(event){
        event.target.classList.remove('disable');
        event.target.classList.add('active');
     },
     setLiDisable(event){
        event.target.classList.remove('active');
        event.target.classList.add('disable');
     }
    
    }

  })
}
callMe();
```

```css
.active a{
color:red
}
.disable a {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   color:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <ul>
    <li class="disable" @mouseleave="setLiDisable($event)"  @mouseover="setLiActive($event)" ><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="disable" @mouseleave="setLiDisable($event)" @mouseover="setLiActive($event)"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li> 
    <li class="active"  @mouseleave="setLiDisable($event)"  @mouseover="setLiActive($event)"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if one of them has the "active" class by default? like

Comment: should work fine as well. Anyways I added one as active by default.

Comment: Basically what I want is that when I mouseover any item, the "active" class has a more "disable" class and when doing mouseout, just delete the class "disable" but keep the class "active" :)

Comment: Your question says something different `add active class` on mouseover & add `disable class on mouseout`